# RAM upgrade with PC2-6400 when specs list PC2-5300 for old Toshiba Satellite L20

Tags: memory, upgrade, toshiba-laptop

I used the [crucial system scanner](http://www.crucial.com/systemscanner/) to check my old Toshiba Satellite L20 and says that I have a maximum of 2GB, with two slots, using a memory type of DDR2 PC2-5300.

I can only find a pair of Kingston DDR2 PC2-6400 2GB sticks and want to know if I can use them when the specifications list PC2-5300.

And instead of using 1GB pairs to make the maximum 2GB could I use just 1 2GB on 1 slot?

Comment: I don't have the manual that's why i resorted to using the system scanner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only supported configurations is outline by the following description straight from the your manual.  Memory will automatically downclock to the support frequency by design.

The Kingston memory you found is not supported by your system.  Based on the description both modules must be filled.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Though a 2gb stick may not be "supported" It is often still able to be used. I have seen several motherboards that could read a 2GB stick in each slot or a 4GB stick in one slot.

As to the downclocking of the ram, should be no problem at all and happen automatically. Also if you were to put it one 6400 and one 3200 (throwing out numbers) they would both operate at 3200

Comment: @PsychoDate it is highly unlikely the system will even boot with 2GB sticks installed based on the chipset used in the author's computer let alone 4GB sticks.

Comment: @Ramhound I didnt say for him to use 4GB sticks in his 1GB board. I did say that I have seen several times where a 4GB worked in place of two 2GB even when only up to 2GB were supported. The same principle might apply that, one 2GB stick might work in place of a two 1GB sticks. I have personally done this. Now using 2 4GB sticks in a board that supports up to 4 GB (2x2GB) I have never seen work. But 1x4GB in a board made for (2x2GB) I have seen work fine

Comment: You have no evidence your suggestion will even work. I can almost guarantee his system will not boot with a single 2GB module.  If the system supported 2GB modules it would be listed.